# Including an Image - ASP.NET MVC View Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've tried over ten various methods of referencing in image within a view (Please don't ask why I'm doing it this way). Anyway obviously one of the biggest problems is that I can never escape the route, even specifying http://localhost:2324:/x/y/img.jpg is pointless.

Is there actually a way referencing an image simply via using file paths?

edit: Pretty sure you can escape the root, Here's an example:

```
<%= ("<img src=”../../vehicleimages/" + Model.vehicleid + ".jpg”  width=“250“ height=“300“ />")%>
```

The result of this would be:

```
<img src=”../../vehicleimages/b480b00e-c725-40fe-a5c2-277e82c5b1d9.jpg”  width=“250“ height=“300“ />
```

All good, however if I click the link within browser source code, it sends me to the following:

```
http://localhost:4716/vehicle/details/vehicleimages/b480b00e-c725-40fe-a5c2-277e82c5b1d9.jpg%E2%80%9D
```

I want `http://localhost:4716/vehicleimages/b480b00e-c725-40fe-a5c2277e82c5b1d9.jpg`

Comment: I think the question is a bit unclear...but sounds interesting! Could you try and add more information about what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Maybe post some example code of what you've tried already...

Comment: That trailing %E2%80%9D translates into ” - it seems you are using the wrong type of qoutation marks in your src attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's your quotation marks that messes things up. Instead of:

```
<%= ("<img src=”../../vehicleimages/" + Model.vehicleid + ".jpg”  width=“250“ height=“300“ />")%>
```

...try either:

```
<img src="../../vehicleimages/<%= Model.vehicleid %>.jpg" width="250" height="300" />
```

...or:

```
<%= ("<img src=\"../../vehicleimages/" + Model.vehicleid + ".jpg\" width=\"250\" height=\"300\" />") %>
```

Comment: Never thought about embedding another tag to include the variable, hah cheers mate, working perfectly